# Sonar does not read Jacoco reports

Tags: maven, build, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a project whose Integration Tests are run by maven-failsafe-plugin and Unit Tests are run by maven-surefire-plugin.

I use jacoco to generate the coverage reports:

```
<properties>
    <coverage.reports.dir>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports</coverage.reports.dir>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${coverage.reports.dir}/jacoco-unit.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${coverage.reports.dir}/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
</properties>

[...]

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.7.201204190339</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</dataFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

[...]

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
          <configuration>
              <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine> 
          </configuration>
    </plugin>

[...]

<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <properties>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
  </properties>
</profile>

[...]
```

When I run mvn install the Jacoco coverage reports are sucessfully generated.

But when I run mvn -mvn -Pdev sonar:sonar Sonar uses the Cobertura plugin instead of Jacoco.

I have tried:

1) Set jacoco as the default coverage plugin in Sonar settings [did not work]

2) Provide Jacoco parameters in the command line (e.g., -Dsonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin=jacoco) [did not work as well]

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

BTW I'm using Sonar 2.8

Comment: did you follow the installation instructions for sonar versions < 2.12 described here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JaCoCo+Plugin? Maybe you should consider upgrading to a newer sonar version, too.

Comment: Yes, I did follow - but it has not worked in any Sonar version I've tried to use. Nevertheless I solved the problem in a (very) ugly way: I've set up the Surefire to kick off both integration and unit tests but in separate executions - therefore I can control when to run the integration tests. And when I run all tests, Cobertura measures the coverage =) It's a horrible solution I know, but worked in the end. Cheers.

Comment: You can refer to below post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483859/how-to-add-jacoco-in-maven/54503124#54503124