# How to add JaCoCo in maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, jacoco

I have written a unit test case using JUnit now I want to add JaCoCo in my build tool that is moving 3.2.1.I am new to Maven. While adding it, I have to doubt that I want to add it in the dependency or plugin ? There are both are available,such that is following

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I desire to append it in the dependency is it enough for the plugin?

Please any body clarify it

Comment: What do you want to do? Have code analyzed in sonar or you want jacoco create analysis reports?

Answer (score 3):

[JaCoCo Java Code Coverage Library](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/)
JaCoCo is a free code coverage library for Java, which has been created by the EclEmma team based on the lessons learned from using and integration existing libraries for many years. <sup>[Example](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/github/alexo/spinner/1.0-SNAPSHOT/spinner-1.0-20141014.200724-1.pom)</sup>

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.9</version>
      <configuration>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <check/>
        <rules>
          <rule>
            <element>CLASS</element>
            <excludes>
                  <exclude>*Test</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <limits>
                  <limit>
                    <counter>LINE</counter>
                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                    <minimum>0.50</minimum>
                  </limit>
            </limits>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>prepare-agent</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>report</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>report</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>check</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <check>
              <instructionRatio>100</instructionRatio>
              <branchRatio>95</branchRatio>
              <lineRatio>90</lineRatio>
              <methodRatio>90</methodRatio>
              <classRatio>90</classRatio>
            </check>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

GitHUb rpository [JaCoCo](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco)

- [Projects that use JaCoCo](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/Projects-that-use-JaCoCo)
- [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/)
- [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add something like the below to your `<build><plugins>`:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-check</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <rule>
                            <element>BUNDLE</element>
                            <limits>
                                <limit>
                                    <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                    <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    <minimum>0.20</minimum>
                                </limit>
                            </limits>
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>   
    </plugin>
```

That should generate you coverage reports in `target/site/jacoco` when you build your project with i.e. `mvn clean install site`

Note in my example plugin configuration the `COVEREDRATIO` limit is very low, you might want to set a higher value like 80 or so. The idea is to let a build fail if coverage is below that limit.

Comment: I have four modules. So In which pom file I want to add it, I mean root module or sub modules? And If I add this plug in Root module then other pom files are showing error

Comment: As Jogesh_D suggests I would add the plugin to `pluginManagement` of your parent POM. You could create a parent POM with all your plugins and common dependencies and reuse it for all your Maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

Add this 2 plugins to pom.xml file. Before adding these plugins make sure you add the dependencies "junit-jupiter-api" and "junit-jupiter-engine". You can find generated HTML file on target > site > jacoco > index.html.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-check</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>PACKAGE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete pom that will help you:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>dummyJar</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>dummyJar</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>            
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The report will be at this location:
/target/site/jacoco/index.html

And see this location for all goals and their config params:
http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

Comment: I have four modules. So In which pom file I want to add it, I mean root module or sub modules? And If I add this plug in Root module then other pom files are showing error...

Comment: If you want to run this for all sub modules add it in the root pom. If you only have a subset of your modules needing to run this then, have a look at plugin management http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management