# How can i give extra parameters in Jacoco, Maven?

Tags: maven, testing, code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a project with multi modules and i have coverage report. I am running with this command:

```
mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent clean install -Pcoverage -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dmaven.test.failurignore=true

But due to multi module, i guess i have to give extra arguments like destfile.
```

How can i do this? For now, some reports are not shown in sonar.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include the jacoco plugin details in your pom file.
See This question for a link to all configuration options for Jacoco.

[How to add JaCoCo in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483859/how-to-add-jacoco-in-maven)